# React-js won't recognize AmbientLightSensor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the sensor's API with react and I can't seen to be able to make it work.

It gives me an error saying that AmbientLightSensor `(in my case this sensor)` is undefined

If I run the script outside react `( more exactly with an extension from VSCode "live server" )` it works fine `( just a html with some JS code in it )`.
That's cool and all but in this case at least I want to run this script inside react and it just doesn't let me.

> So far I've tried:

- running this code in react as a class method called by componentDidMount and that (Simply i've put my JS code in there ^^ )
- running this code with the  tag hoping that maybe react isn't really using the JS that I know and that maybe running it inside html will change this ... No it didn't do the trick
  So at this point I'm unsure what to even check to make this work

Here is my code, the js code I'm trying to run is inside the Did mount component

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const details = document.getElementById("details");

        // Feature detection
        if (window.AmbientLightSensor) {
            try {
                const sensor = new AmbientLightSensor();
                // Detect changes in the light
                sensor.onreading = () => {
                    details.innerHTML = sensor.illuminance;

                    // Read the light levels in lux
                    // < 50 is dark room
                    if (sensor.illuminance < 50) {
                        document.body.className = "darkLight";
                    } else {
                        document.body.className = "brightLight";
                    }
                };

                // Has an error occured?
                sensor.onerror = event =>
                    (document.getElementById("details").innerHTML =
                        event.error.message);
                sensor.start();
            } catch (err) {
                details.innerHTML = err.message;
            }
        } else {
            details.innerHTML =
                "It looks like your browser doesnt support this feature";
        }
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <h1>Ambient Light Sensor</h1>
                <p>Current Light Levels</p>
                <div id="details"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And also here is the working html

````
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Ambient Light Sensor</title>
</head>

<body class="brightLight">
    <h1>Ambient Light Sensor</h1>
    <p>Current Light Levels</p>
    <div id="details"></div>
</body>
<script>
    const details = document.getElementById("details");

    // Feature detection
    if (window.AmbientLightSensor) {
        try {
            const sensor = new AmbientLightSensor();
            // Detect changes in the light
            sensor.onreading = () => {
                details.innerHTML = sensor.illuminance;

                // Read the light levels in lux
                // < 50 is dark room
                if (sensor.illuminance < 50) {
                    document.body.className = "darkLight";
                } else {
                    document.body.className = "brightLight";
                }
            };

            // Has an error occured?
            sensor.onerror = event =>
                (document.getElementById("details").innerHTML =
                    event.error.message);
            sensor.start();
        } catch (err) {
            details.innerHTML = err.message;
        }
    } else {
        details.innerHTML =
            "It looks like your browser doesnt support this feature";
    }
</script>

</html>```

PS* for this to work you need to run this on a https server
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how React works...

I'd suggest looking into `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` link here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

And `createRef` link here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs

Here is a simple example utilizing both to give you a better idea:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.detailsRef = React.createRef();
  }

  createMarkup() {
    return { __html: 'whatever you want...' };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.detailsRef.current.innerHTML);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <h1>Ambient Light Sensor</h1>
        <p>Current Light Levels</p>
        <div
          ref={this.detailsRef}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.createMarkup()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Play around with it and read the links from the official docs to adapt to your specific use case...

Answer (score 1):

Never used the `AmbientLightSensor`API before but: try something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            details: ''
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (window.AmbientLightSensor) {
            try {
                const sensor = new AmbientLightSensor();

                sensor.onreading = () => {
                    this.setState({ details: sensor.illuminance });

                    if (sensor.illuminance < 50) {
                        document.body.className = 'darkLight';
                    } else {
                        document.body.className = 'brightLight';
                    }
                };
                sensor.onerror = event =>
                    this.setState({ details: event.error.message });

                sensor.start();
            } catch (err) {
                this.setState({ details: err.message });
            }
        } else {
            this.setState({
                details:
                    'It looks like your browser doesnt support this feature'
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <h1>Ambient Light Sensor</h1>
                <p>Current Light Levels</p>
                <div id="details">{this.state.details}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that adding ha className to the body like that is a good idea...

Comment: @SakoBu yea you are right it may not exactly a great idea...but since he has no access to it in itself, and since I really do not know what he is trying to achieve (He may have other components etc attached), I have no way of knowing how to replace that aspect

Comment: AmbientLightSensor is not defined no-undef

Comment: Thank you for taking you'r time though ^^

Comment: @IonutEugen I kind of expected that error...I assumed it was local to me...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got it :D
The only working way I found to send a JavaScript file and run it `is by declaring it in the index.html file inside the public folder` ( if u made the app with create react app )

```
Normally react servers you this file and it adds it's components over it.
```

The reason why running the script inside a react class won't do ( as far as I managed to understand ) is that react isn't actually running `JavaScript` there but a language based on top of `JavaScript ES6`.

While this means that most functionalities you may be accustomed with are working in it there are exceptions too, mostly to new functionalities ( as the sensor's API, its pretty new ).

This may not be a problem in the future, but for the time being I guess this is one way to do it.

> Edit * And @SakoBu's answer turned out to be the safe way of doing
>   this
>
> ( #Change my mind meme :3 )